# Does the trace of a Levi-Civita connection always vanish?

Tags: trace, connections

If $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ are the Christoffel symbols of the Levi-Civita connection corresponding to the metric tensor $\boldsymbol{g}$, i.e., if $$\Gamma^a_{bc} = \tfrac{1}{2} \, g^{ad} (g_{cd,b} + g_{bd,c} - g_{bc,d}),$$ does it follow that $\Gamma^b_{bc} = 0$? Thank you for any help you can give.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Why would it?
It's just $\Gamma^{a}_{ac} = \frac{1}{2}g^{ad}(g_{cd,a} + g_{ad,c}-g_{ac,d})$, which in fact reduces to
$\Gamma^{a}_{ac} = (\log(\sqrt{|\det(g)|}))_{,c}$
You can read the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309535/a-helpful-proof-in-contracting-the-christoffel-symbol) for a derivation.

Comment: Thanks, I got to the same conclusion in the same way, but I forgot to remove the question from Stackexchange. Thanks for the suggested expression in terms of the determinant of the metric.